# How to check conflicts on multiple dates from a single query

Tags: python, database, postgresql, join, web2py

I'm working on a booking system (in Python-web2py) and I'm trying to optimize my code. The problem is that I have multiple dates (more than 50) and I need to list conflicts for each of those dates. Doing this in a loop is very time-consuming, therefore I'm looking for a query that can do this. Any thoughts?
The current clause for checking conflicts is:

```
((db.booking.booking_end > booking_start_utc) & (db.booking.booking_start < booking_end_utc))
```

Comment: why do you use both utc and local (or not?) times?

Comment: @ElenaNNN I'm using only utc time. The database contains utc values for booking_start and booking_end.

Comment: Try to use EXPLAIN ANALYZE http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-explain.html . You will see weaknesses. Or post its result.

Comment: Are you saying you need to loop over 50+ pairs of `(booking_start_utc, booking_end_utc)` values?

Comment: @ElenaNNN the query is already optimized (it is checking a very limited number of rows, I've confirmed that with EXPLAIN). Executing the query takes about 150-250 ms. The loop is what is drastically reducing the performance.
50 * 150 is a lot of milliseconds.

Comment: @Anthony Yes. Now, I've saved the start dates and end dates in separate lists and I'm OR-ing them (in a loop) to the query clause. This seems to be working better. Is this the right way to go or is there a better approach?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the right approach, and I have provided an answer along those lines (though using `reduce` and a list comprehension rather than a loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of start times and a list of associated end times, you can construct a single query including all start/end times:

```
times = zip(start_times, end_times)
query = reduce(lambda a, b: a | b,
               [(db.booking.booking_end > start) &
                (db.booking.booking_start < end) for start, end in times])
conflicts = db(query).select()
```

The above will produce a query like:

```
((db.booking.booking_end > s1) & (db.booking.booking_start < e1)) |
((db.booking.booking_end > s2) & (db.booking.booking_start < e2)) |
...
((db.booking.booking_end > s50) & (db.booking.booking_start < e50))
```

Comment: How should I put the dates in this format (s1, e1)?

Comment: `zip(start_times, end_times)`. I updated the answer.